# Tor Browser: "Connection not secure" no matter what site

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, error, ssl, certificate

I get an error "Connection not secure" if I connect to any website using Tor Browser. I get this error only when I use Tor Browser in Manjaro Linux, I have no problem if I use Tor Browser in Windows or Android. Version of Tor Browser is currently latest - 0.3.3-1. Also, I tried to use Firefox browser with Tor proxy, and it works okay. Also, I guess as a result of this I can't visit GitHub website or see Google Captcha.
Screenshots: [image: GitHub] [image: no Google Captcha].

By the way, I use standard security level.
Hope for your help!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your "Connection not secure" message, and also post the IP address of the exit relay you're using when you get that message (you can find this by clicking the lock icon next to the address)?

Comment: @Steve, yes, screenshot: https://ibb.co/Ry6SQLK. p.s: I tried to change exit relay, didn't help

Comment: Thanks, that "Connection not secure" warning isn't normal, but I'm not sure what's going wrong, especially if it happens on most websites and with different exit relays.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Everything worked perfectly then suddenly, same error. Any chance you figured out the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/40328

> Version of Tor Browser is currently latest - 0.3.3-1.

That's either severely outdated or not the Tor Browser version. Current TB version is 10.0.12.

> Also, I guess as a result of this I can't visit GitHub website or see Google Captcha.

I do not know.